# strange little triangle appears at the top corner of imageView

Tags: android

I am using firebase storage to store images for my application so I can downloaded them using picasso when I need them in different activities, every thing was perfect suddenly with no reason a little strange triangle appears at the top corner of the following imageView

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgVisitedUserImageId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cover_image"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/unknown" />
```

when I comment out the Picasso image download line

```
Picasso.with(ProfileActivity.this).load(visitedImage).placeholder(R.drawable.unknown).into(visitedUserImage);
```

and setImageResource to the imageview using any image every thing goes fine and the image is set well without that strange green triangle
any help I will be thankful.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08KCT.png)

Comment: Its a memory debug indicator of Picasso . You need to disable it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that green triangle is actually a debug indicators coming through Picasso library. I am wondering it's coming though you haven't called setIndicatorsEnabled method!

**What are debug indicators?**
Debug indicators is actually for development to enable the display of a colored ribbon which indicates the image source. You can call `setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` on the Picasso instance to enable it and false for disabling it.

[image]

Refer documentation for more details http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: thannnnnk you verrrrrrrrry much I appreciate your answer I really helped, I have been trying to figure out what I did for about an hour you saved my day I am sorry I don't have enough reputations to thumb up your answer

Comment: @MohammadElsayed Glad to help! Cheers last day of the year.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that somewhere in your app you are setting Picassos debug indicators to true. See the documentation for reference http://square.github.io/picasso/